# Nature's Way ability clarification

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I don't understand the last line of [Nature's Way](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNature%27s%5d%2b%5bWay%5d):

> It deals damage equal to its power to target creature [...]

Does it mean when I cast this card, one of my creatures gains vigilance and trample and also deals damage (like an instant)? And after this, can I also attack with this creature?

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome. Perhaps wait a bit before accepting an answer, as folks are less likely to answer, and you might get more information that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your creature becomes an illegal target when the spell resolves (your opponent could play a removal spell on the creature you have chosen in response to you playing Nature's Way), your creature will deal damage to a creature your opponent controls (again, unless it became an illegal target).

The ability won't cause your creature to tap, so you can still attack with it.

Comment: Not the case that the first ability needs to resolve in order for second to resolve. They are separate. Can't think of an example where something is prevented from gaining trample, but it doesn't *have* to in order for the damage to be dealt. (-1)

Comment: It's worse than that. 1) There's only one ability. You mean "effect". 2) Neither the ability or its effects resolve. Only the spell is on the stack and resolves. 3) The first effect doesn't need to be successful for the second effect to happen. Fixed.

Comment: I've expanded the answer. Actually, the first effect has to happen for the second one to happen, it's even in the Nature's Way rullings: "If either target is an illegal target as Nature’s Way resolves, no damage will be dealt."

Comment: That doesn't mean that the creature needs to gain vigilance or trample for the damage to happen.

Comment: Given "609.3. If an effect attempts to do something impossible, it does only as much as possible." so, if for some reason the creature haven't got vigilance or trample, the effect still happened, just did nothing.

Answer (score 6):

**Does Nature's Way deal damage like an instant?**

Sort of. Your thinking is correct that Nature's Way is similar to an instant in that it causes damage. If you choose a creature with 3 power as the first target, it would behave similar to a [Lightning Bolt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLightning%20Bolt%5d).

On the other hand, there are many differences between Nature's Way and Lightning Bolt. Nature's Way is not the source of damage. Your creature is. This matters if, for example, your creature has deathtouch. Also, Nature's Way is a sorcery, which restricts when you are allowed to cast it.

**Can my creature attack afterwards?**

Sure. Your creatures don't give up and die (or tap) for no reason. Nature's Way makes your creature deal damage, but it doesn't make the other creature deal damage back. If the card said "fight" then it would become a two-way exchange.